# Accessing local IIS site from my Android device (HTC Desire HD)

Tags: android, iis, local

I am making a website. I'm using IIS7 on a Windows 7 Professional machine.
Is there a way I can acces that local site from HTC Desire HD (Android 2.2)?

I have tried connecting my phone through the internet via the internet passthrough option that is available on Desire HD. I can connect through my PC, but not to my local site.

I have also tried making an inbound rule in my firewall on port 80 but to no avail. (I saw someone mention this somewhere)

I would appreciate some help on this one.

/Anders

Answer (score 2):

The site is currently running on your local network? If so, it's probably available at localhost/ or your local IP, correct?

If it's the only site running on that server/port combination, you can enable your firewall for that port, enable WiFi on your phone and just go to the computer's LAN IP which should bring up the site.

If this isn't specific enough, let me know in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for you response. Unfortunately it didn't work.
I have a number of sites running on my local machine that I have mapped in IIS7 (I'm no expert, so if I use some words wrong, I'm sorry). So for example I have a local site the I acces in my browser by typing local.site.com and another where I type homepage.site.com and a few others that aren't interesting at this point. I hope this clarification can bring up some more answers :)

Comment: The easiest, in this case, would be to run the sites on different ports. So if you ran local.site.com on 80, homepage.site.com on 81 etc. etc. - on your android you can then go to your machine's IP on Wifi, with the appropriate port number, and see the site. So 192.168.1.1:80 or :81. I'm not familiar with IIS, so I don't know how simple it is to have one site per port running.

The complicated version is setting up a DNS in your local network, but let's not worry about that. The former is easier to do.